# PHP/MySQL tree that is inifinite

Tags: php, mysql, tree, infinite, search-tree

I've got a tree-algorithm and database problem I'd like to have an answer to.

I've got a few areas, let's say 20. Each of these areas have sub-areas ~ 20 each.
These **parent areas are spread out on a map**. **Some of these parent areas are close to eachother.**

The database looks like this: **[area_id, title, parent_id]** - Some has multiple children, there's a root node containing all areas. *(The Adjacency List Model)*

To make this in a picture I could do this:[image: Basic Tree View]

The different areas as I said, can be close to eachother, (or far away). I'd like someway to tie let's say **Area 1 and Area 5 together** because I know they're close, and **Area 1 is also close to Area 4.** Now, here's the problem, let's say that **Area 4 is also close to Area 5.**

It would look like something like this:[image: Problem tree]

Which makes it an infitite loop? because I want **Area 1 to be close to Area 4, but also Area 4 is close to Area 1.**

I'd like to do a search, where you can select *"search nearby areas"*, so you select one area then you can search the nearby ones. I could use some tips, on how to solve this with a database and php.

I've been looking around on this forum for help but I don't really know the "name" of this problem, I'd be happy if someone could point me in the right direction or straight up help me out in thist thread.

**Thanks guys,** and if it's something else you need to know I'll try to answer as soon as possible.

Comment: I don't get why you **really** need to **repeat** AREA 1 -> AERA 5, AERA 4... The first time could be enough to know that these three nodes are bound.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The question then is, how would something like that look in a database? with around 20 areas that are connected in different ways (close to each other), it would be a really big table, just for 20 areas, right ?

Answer (score 1):

For anything that is dealing with proximity, I would certainly take an approach of putting in either geospatial information (if these are true areas/regions) and then applying a radial search which can be done via any number of simple through to complex queries and calculations.

If these places are on the other hand fictional, it might be interesting to consider making a fake location - even if it a simple x,y coordinate system. This will allow you to perform radial searches again - which you can enlarge or shrink to your needs - or even simply order the results in ascending distance from site a to b.

Comment: This bascially means you make an X-Y coordinate system and calculate the distance between them ? The problem is that some of them are touching eachother (neighboring) and those are the areas I want to find, bascially the closest areas that are touching, I'll have a look at the radial search, thanks!

Comment: Yeah, if you are using long/lat you want to use the [Haversine Formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula) otherwise it is a simple [coordinate Distance](http://www.mathopenref.com/coorddist.html) calculation.

Answer (score 1):

To subdivide an area you need a rectangle that you can split along the axis. Look at kd-tree, r-tree, or quadtrees and spatial index. I can recommend you my php class Hilbert curve. It's a monster curve and fills completely the plane. You can find it at phpclasses.org.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look at it!

Answer (score -1):

I finally solved it using a kind of "neighboring" select statment.

I did this by creating another table which contains neighbor-relationships. That table looked like: **[table_id, area_id, neighbor_area_id]**

Here I added all the neighbors that are avaliable, with some INNER JOIN and select statment I managed to get out what I wanted, so a search can be done for all areas neighboring the selected one.

The sql-statment looked like this:

```
SELECT adds.title, categories.title, area.title
FROM adds
INNER JOIN categories ON categories.category_id = adds.category_id
INNER JOIN areas ON adds.area_id = areas.area_id
WHERE areas.area_id IN (SELECT area_neighbors.area_neighbor_id 
                        FROM area_neighbors 
                        WHERE area_id='25')
OR adds.area_id='25'
```

This would give me all adds in neighboring areas to area_id 25.

I cannot say if this is the **smartest or best solution** but it's one that works for me. Hope this helps someone! and thanks for all the replies!

Comment: It's something I came up with myself. I make the neighbor column by adding the id's that are "neighbors" to the area id myself.